# Trigger the event when selected the same value in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Issue: I have a dropdown with a list of years in it with nothing selected, the user selects "1976", I run a function. If the user clicks on the dropdown again and selects "1976" AGAIN, I want to run the function again.

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) 
{
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value; 
alert(valueSelected);      
});
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no generic event that triggers when a select dropdown is closed.

Comment: @David I agree. Perhaps the issue is the design of the UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Simple JS
---------

<html>
<head>
<script>
var prevIndex = "";

function onSelect()
{
    var currIndex = document.getElementById("ddList").selectedIndex;
    if( currIndex > 0 )
    {
        if( prevIndex != currIndex )
        {
            alert("Selected Index = " + currIndex);
            prevIndex = currIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            prevIndex = "";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="ddList" onClick="onSelect()">
        <option value="0">Select Me</option>
        <option value="1">List1</option>
        <option value="2">List2</option>
        <option value="3">List3</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Prabathi, i have done with hidden element. check my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

This basic idea should work using jQuery using click event:

```
$('#yourselect').click(function() {
  console.log("your function");
});
```

A simple if statement could prevent firing off the function when initially clicking the select element.

Comment: Change won't fire again if the user chooses the same value. This is behaviour OP specifically requires

Comment: click event works when selecting the same value again

Comment: what if the user changes the second time? I think answer needs to handle both

Answer (score 1):

The closest functionality that you're seeking that I can think of is the following:

-HTML-

```
<select class="opt-evt">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
</select>
```

-jQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.opt-evt').change(function(){
        $(this).blur();
    }).blur(function(){
        console.log($(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });

});
```

The caveat is that if the user selects '1976' again, the desired event only gets fired onBlur.

http://jsfiddle.net/4G9Jf/

Answer (score 0):

mouseup event should do the trick:

```
$('select').mouseup(function(){
    console.log("hue");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Fcgr/

note that this will be triggered twice when a new value is selected in the listbox. Once when opening the options, and once when selecting an option.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed as below,

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function onSelect()
{
    var dd = document.getElementById('ddList');
    var txtTerms = document.getElementById('selValue');            
    var storeLstSlct = document.getElementById('checkIndx');
    var slctdValue = '';   

    if(dd.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }else if(storeLstSlct.value == dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value)
    {              
        storeLstSlct.value = 'abcd'; 
        return false;              
    }else
    {                            
        slctdValue = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;    
        if(txtTerms.value != '')                     
            txtTerms.value = txtTerms.value + ' , ' + slctdValue;
        else
            txtTerms.value = slctdValue;  
        storeLstSlct.value = slctdValue;              
    }
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<select id='ddList' onclick='onSelect()'>
<option value='0'>Select Me</option>
<option value='One'>List1</option>
<option value='Two'>List2</option>
<option value='Three'>List3</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='checkIndx' id='checkIndx' />
<input type='text' name='selValue' id='selValue' />
</body>
</html>
```