# drop down onchange selected list not working?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Drop down not working when I select same option second time.
This is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>
        <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
            <option value="Audi">Audi
            <option value="BMW">BMW
            <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
            <option value="Volvo">Volvo
        </select>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
                alert(x);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

First time select any care eg:Audi, then it alerts Audi, after alert again select Audi then there is no alert coming. Could anybody help me whats wrong in this?

Comment: seem to be working fine here.. http://jsfiddle.net/s2n15ydo/

Comment: select BMW shows alert,again select BMW then observe?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar,you got it what i'm trying to say?

Comment: do you want it to fire everytime you select some value.. even if its already selected?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar,obsolutely yes

Comment: @GangadharB i have update my answer..check it now

Comment: @Usman,thank you.Its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you select the same option TWICE so there is no change in `selected` object of `Dropdown`.

Try like below

**Updated Answer**

```
var dd = document.getElementById('mySelect');          
var storeLstSlct = document.getElementById('checkIndx');
var slctdValue = '';   

if(dd.selectedIndex == 0)
{
    return false;
}else if(storeLstSlct.value == dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value)
{              
    storeLstSlct.value = 'garbage'; 
    return false;              
}else
{                            
    slctdValue = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;    
  alert(slctdValue); 
    storeLstSlct.value = slctdValue;              
}
```

Fiddle is **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1b2jf9qc/4/)**

Comment: Usman,In my requirement i need to use only html and javascript.Could you help me how to change?

Comment: Who said he is using jquery? Don't include it without the call.

Comment: @GangadharB .. is there any way you can use JQuery??

Comment: @Usman,the problem is due to Onchange.is there option to replace it?

Comment: @Usman,have you checked for Audi option ,not working.except everyting is fine.

Comment: @GangadharB mark the answer as correct one if it is as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The event is onchange when you try to select the item already selected change event wont fire.

Comment: then whats the other way to do with html and javascript?

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close option tags and to do this you need to attach onclick event handler to all of the options in the dropdown, see below:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");

//attach onclick event handlers to options
for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) 
{
  if (x.options[i].addEventListener) 
  { 
    /*all other browsers*/
    x.options[i].addEventListener("click", function() {mysFunction(this)}, false);
  } 
  else if (x.options[i].attachEvent) /*ie < 9*/ 
  {
    x.options[i].attachEvent("click", function() {mysFunction(this)});
  }
}

//execute my alert box on item select
function mysFunction(elem) {
  alert(elem.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that's not a problem sir

Comment: @RobinVanPersi The edited answer as well doesn't address OP's problem.

Comment: @AwalGarg - did you even bother testing the script? did you even bother reading the question? please re-read the question and see whether this solution fixes the problem or not. from my end it works and it addresses the problem

Comment: @GangadharB - I just tested it and it works from my end. I'm using FF v33

Comment: @RobinVanPersi,select Mercedez then after alert again select Merce,then observe

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this??](http://jsfiddle.net/chakrei/ttuegLoj/)

Add the following code

```
    $('option').click(function(){  
       alert($(this).text());
    });
```

Unfortunately, the above method will not work in "Chrome", try in "Internet Explorer" or "Mozialla" (atleast IE is being used for this reason :p )

Answer (score 0):

**Update with Demo :** http://jsbin.com/hujavalayu/1/edit

I hope this will satisfy your requirement, Please check the link

[Trigger the event when selected the same value in dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354112/trigger-the-event-when-selected-the-same-value-in-dropdown)

```
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>
<select id="ddList" onClick="onSelect()">
    <option value="0">Select Me</option>
    <option value="List1">List1</option>
    <option value="List2">List2</option>
    <option value="List3">List3</option>
</select>


<script>
    var prevIndex = "";

    function onSelect() {
        var currIndex = document.getElementById("ddList").selectedIndex;
        if (currIndex > 0) {
            if (prevIndex != currIndex) {
                alert("Selected Value = " + document.getElementById("ddList").value);
                prevIndex = currIndex;
            } else {
                prevIndex = "";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `onclick="this.value=null"` and define your `onchange` as well,
so every time you select any option it will clear the selected item and you can select same option again ;).
Here is the sample Code:

```js
$serial_no = 0;

<select id="<?php echo $serial_no++; ?>" onclick="this.value=null" onchange="update_value(this.value,this.id)" class="form-control" required>
  <option><?php echo $row['card']; ?></option>
  <option>---------</option>
  <option>Pending</option>
  <option>Deliver</option>
</select>

update_value(item){
  alert(item);
}
```